# Getting 'can't $Subtract a date from a string' in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have written this MongoDB code to get the difference between the emp_head start date and end date, but I am getting an error -

> can't $Subtract a date from a string

Here is my code:

```
db.department.aggregate([{$lookup: {
 from: 'employees',
 localField: 'dept_id',
 foreignField: 'dept_id',
 as: 'employees_list'
}}, {$set: {
 employees: {
  $objectToArray: '$employees_list'
 }
}}, {$set: {
 Dt_diff: {
  $map: {
   input: '$employees',
   as: 'b',
   'in': {
    k: '$$b.k',
    v: {
     $divide: [
      {
       $subtract: [
        '$$b.v.start_dt',
        '$$b.v.end_dt'
       ]
      },
      86400000
     ]
    }
   }
  }
 }
}}, {$match: {
 'Dt_diff.v': {
  $elemMatch: {
   $gt: 14
  }
 }
}}])
```

I am using Compass to create this aggregation, and I am getting proper output, and able to get the difference between the two dates until the 3rd $set stage, but when I use the $match operator, it gives the above error.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Here is my document :

```
{ _id: ObjectId("6188a5283543f7cc2f77c73f"),
  dept_id: 1,
  emp_list: 
   { '0': 
      { start_dt: 2021-08-15T06:00:00.000Z,
        emp_head: 'ID000067',
        end_dt: 2021-08-25T06:00:00.000Z } },
  employees_list: 
   [ { _id: ObjectId("6147925cb38887fa243c2389"),
       empId: ['ID000067','ID000090','ID000012','ID000065','ID000047'] } ],
  employees: 
   [ { k: '0',
       v: 
        { start_dt: 2021-08-15T06:00:00.000Z,
          emp_head: 'ID000067',
          end_dt: 2021-08-25T06:00:00.000Z } } ],
  Dt_diff: [ { k: '0', v: 10 } ] }
```

Comment: would be helpful if you can provide your sample document in JSON format

Comment: Please provide valid sample data. Anyway, the error messages is quite clear. Storing date/time values as string is a design flaw, you should **never** do that. Store always proper `Date` objects.

Comment: @ray I added the sample document in JSON. Can you please check now?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I added the sample document in JSON. Can you please check now? I have stored dates in the ISO date format.

Comment: Most likely somewhere in your collection you stored `start_dt` or/and `end_dt` as string rather than a `Date`. You should find the non-Date values with query like `{ $match: { end_dt: { $not: { $type: 'date' } } } }` Note, In MongoDB version 5 you can use `{ $dateDiff: { startDate: "$start_dt", endDate: "$end_dt", unit: "day" } }`

Comment: You want to wrap the dates you use in Mongodb Compass into an `ISODate` like this: `mydate: ISODate('2021-08-25T06:00:00.000Z')`